# How to call a RESTful API after drupal node in created, updated or deleted

Tags: php, rest, drupal

I am using Drupal 7 and wanted to know how can we call a RESTful API after drupal node in created, updated or deleted in drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal supports "hook" funcitions system. That is, you implement function in your module with some special name, clear the cache, drupal notice that function and in appropriate time it calls it.

I.e.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x

Meaning, in your module you should make functions called `mymodule_node_update()` (where "mymodule" is name of your module, meaning you have to create module first) and when any kind of node is updated (saved) your function will be called so you can do your stuff.

Same goes for creating/deleting - just search for hook functions.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple Drupal Module which implements
hook_node_insert for inserts (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x)

hook_node_delete for deletes.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7.x

Within this function invoke curl http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

We do this for invoking calls to a backend php rest service and to 3rd party services such as go to webinar. Works great.